# Why can't server and client be started together?

Tags: java, multithreading

Relevant code:

```java
 @Test
    public void serverTest() throws IOException {
        GameServer server = new GameServer();
        server.start(9000);
        GameClient client1 = new GameClient();
        GameClient client2 = new GameClient();
        client1.startConnection("localhost", 9000);
        client2.startConnection("localhost", 9000);
        client1.sendMessage("Hey I am client 1");
        client2.sendMessage("Hey I am client 2");

    }
```

```java
public class GameServer {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public void start(int port) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Server started !!!");
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        while (true) {
            new Thread(new GameClientHandler(serverSocket.accept())).start();
        }
    }

    public void stop() throws IOException {
        serverSocket.close();
    }


   private static class GameClientHandler implements Runnable {
        private Socket clientSocket;
        private PrintWriter out;
        private BufferedReader in;

        public GameClientHandler(Socket socket) {
            this.clientSocket = socket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                String inputLine = in.readLine();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.print(inputLine);
                }


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            try {
                in.close();
                out.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Why can't the server and client be started together in the `@Test`? I think it gets stuck in the infinite while loop but at the same time, shouldn't there be context switching with the new threads started after accepting the connection?

I expected at least the name of the 2 new threads to be printed but it doesn't happen.

Comment: Your question is unclear and is missing information. `GameClientHandler` where is this defined and what does it contain? What are you expecting to happen with your code?

Comment: Why would context switching cause the the while loop to break?

Comment: @rushi I meant the main thread could be paused and the program could go to one of the newly created threads.

Comment: Start your server in a separate thread.

Comment: @GoldCredential, where is `GameClient` defined?

Comment: @Antoniossss But why? That is my question.

Comment: @kiner_shah I don't think it's relevant to the question..

Comment: To not to block the main thread which executes the infinite loop

Comment: The other threads are NOT started. Before starting a new thread, you get stuck on the `serverSocket.accept()` call which is blocking forever, waiting for some client to connect on the socket. Move that call into the handlers, perhaps, or into a separate thread. Only then will the handler thread start. Still, you'd never exit the loop and therefore never start any clients, so you still need to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us look carefully to your test code:

```
    GameServer server = new GameServer();
```

Ok, this lines creates a server, and the test thread is ready to execute next line

```
    server.start(9000);
```

Ok, the test thread starts the server, and **will be ready to execute the next line when the `start` method will return**.

What happens in `start`:

```
    System.out.println("Server started !!!");
```

Ok, you should see that message

```
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
```

Ok, you have created a `ServerSocket`

```
    while (true) {
        new Thread(new GameClientHandler(serverSocket.accept())).start();
    }
```

ok you a waiting for a connection (at `serverSocket.accept()`), will create a new thread to handle it as soon as you will get one, and loop again.

But as this point, the test thread is waiting and will never go to the following line to start the first connection. And it will remain stuck unless *something else* (maybe another thread) starts those damned connections.

Comment: Exactly. Just to make it a little more clear, the code will wait forever at the `serverSocket.accept()` call (which is called before the `new Thread(...)` part) and will never move on from there.

Answer (score 1):

The method `GameServer.start` will only return with an exception. That is because you have the while-loop.

So your test execution will start the server and wait for someone to open a connection, but that never happens.

Comment: But I also have client1.startConnection()?

Comment: You never get to `client1.startConnection()`. Your code is stuck forever at `serverSocket.accept()` which waits forever. It will not move from that point. Even if that was not the case, the then there's the infinite loop. Again, the code would loop forever, never actually getting to `client1.startConnection()`.

Comment: @PetrJaneček
Regarding the latter part of your comment, If a thread is looping forever, it is impossible to switch to another thread?

Comment: It can. This is not about other threads. Other threads will run the `GameClientHandler.run()` code, but not anything else. What's happening, is this: Thread1: "I'll wait for a client to connect. When it connects, I'll start a thread to handle it, then wait for another connection, and another, and another, and another. When infinite connections are done (never), only then will I move on and actually start two clients." This thread gets stuck at step 1, waiting for a client to connect. There are no clients. There are no other (handler) threads because you only start them after a client connects.

Comment: It is possible, but at that point there are no other threads. If there were any, they'd run. Every thread has its own code. This is not magic, code cannot jump between threads. Code still must be executed sequentially by a single thread. Therefore, you need to wait for client connections in one thread, and start clients in another thread. The server needs to have its own thread which will handle the connections. The infinite loop will hog the thread forever and the code after Server.start() never runs.